# SQL Select All Columns with grouped 2 columns have count = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select 3 columns from a table based on the first 2 columns (as a group) only having a `count = 1`. Once they have been identified i would like to bring in the 3rd column of that row.

This statement works for the first 2 columns but i can't add the 3rd column as i don't want the search group to be defined by this.

```
SELECT
  Defect_Point,
  Report_Num
FROM MyCount
GROUP BY Defect_Point,
         Report_Num
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Any Ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Note: if the count is always 1 then getting the `MAX(thirdcol)` will produce what you want here, because the max thirdcol will always be the single value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you could use the over clause and a subquery to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
Select
  Defect_Point, Report_Num, Third_Column,
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Defect_Point, Report_Num) AS your_count
from MyCount
) a
WHERE your_count = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, getting closer i think. The final result i'm after is to get a count of all the rows in the table where Defect_Point, Report_Num are a distinct group and the Third Column = "MyString". Not sure if that's clear or not..

Comment: @Ryan I think is clear, it would requiere to add `Third_Column = 'MyString'` in the WHERE and COUNT instead to show the columns... but that wasn't what you asked. It's kind of rude changing the question or asking for more after someone answered.

Comment: apologies i didn't mean offence. I thought at the time the question was how i wanted it to sound...

Answer (score 0):

You can try following also:

```
select 
  contact_uid, 
  group_uid 
from 
  relation;
```

(12 56), 
(15 56)
(15 57),
(12 55),
(12 56)

```
SELECT
  contact_uid,
  group_uid
FROM relation
WHERE group_uid IN (SELECT
  group_uid
FROM relation
GROUP BY group_uid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1);
```

Sorry, don't know how to beautify that but those are the values of columns contact uid and group uid.